# Semantic UI - Textarea inside a <td> with different format

Tags: html, css, styles, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic for the styling of a project and I need to insert into a field  from a table a textarea but the styling from the textarea doesn't seem to be respected, it looks ugly.

In the table I also use some other semantic objects, but they weren´t affected, the look like it should.

Here´s an image of how it looks:

[image]
As you can see, the textarea doesn´t look like it should. But the other things look fine.

Here's the code of the table:

```
<table class = "ui celled stripped table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Nombre
                </th>
                <th>
                    Personalidad
                </th>
                <th>
                    Pide extensión
                </th>
                <th>
                    Contexto
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class = "collapsing">
                    Nombre nombre apellido apellido
                </td>
                <td class = "collapsing">
                    <div class = "ui multiple search selection dropdown" dropdown-search-personalities>
                        <input type = "hidden">
                        <i class = "dropdown icon"></i>
                        <div class = "default text">Selecciona...</div>
                        <div class = "menu">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class = "collapsing">
                    <div class="ui fitted slider checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox"> <label></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class = "collapsing">
                    <textarea></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Am I missing a class for the textarea? The semantic docs doesn´t show any class to add for the textarea...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Semantic UI textarea may be used only inside `<div class='ui form'>` or `<Form>` elements.

Answer (score -1):

You might have overrode the Semantic UI css with your own css for the textarea. It doesn't look weird if you just use the default semantic files. Check your custom css files.

```js
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<table class = "ui celled stripped table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Nombre
                </th>
                <th>
                    Personalidad
                </th>
                <th>
                    Pide extensión
                </th>
                <th>
                    Contexto
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class = "collapsing">
                    Nombre nombre apellido apellido
                </td>
                <td class = "collapsing">
                    <div class = "ui multiple search selection dropdown" dropdown-search-personalities>
                        <input type = "hidden">
                        <i class = "dropdown icon"></i>
                        <div class = "default text">Selecciona...</div>
                        <div class = "menu">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class = "collapsing">
                    <div class="ui fitted slider checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox"> <label></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class = "collapsing">
                    <textarea></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```